# How to use Common Data Model (CDM) Schema in my .Net Core application

Tags: c#, schema, database-schema, data-modeling

I would like my application to benefit from a common data scheme to facilitate analytics and integration with other systems (Power BI and Dynamics come to mind).  I have found the `Common Data Model (CDM) Schema` by Microsoft and want to understand better how this is used in practice with a .Net application.  The "How to" information published by Microsoft seems to focus on Power Apps, but not how an implementation would look like for other frameworks.

On the [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/CDM) page I have found resources for C# projects, which includes object interfaces (not specific entity interfaces as far as I can tell) and some tooling (adapters and tests).
In addition, in the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/common-data-model/schema/core/applicationcommon/overview) I have found definitions of the entities.

Now I would like to understand the best way to benefit from the CDM schema:

1. Do I write my own classes/entities of which the properties are in line with the linked [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/common-data-model/schema/core/applicationcommon/overview) on what entities should look like?  Or are these entities available as classes in a Microsoft supplied namespace?
2. a) If I write my own classes, can I pick and choose which properties I implement?  Or can I only benefit from common functionality when I implement 100% of the listed properties? b) How do I support properties outside the ones defined by Microsoft and still have these properties work outside my application?
   c) If I can skip properties, will functionality outside my application (PowerBi etc) fail softly when expected properties are not available?
3. It's not obvious to me which interfaces (as supplied on [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/CDM/tree/master/objectModel/CSharp/Microsoft.CommonDataModel.ObjectModel/Cdm)) need to be implemented for which entities (as listed in the Microsoft hosted documentation), how do I know what to implement for which entity?

I would be very happy if anyone can supply any relevant resources (.Net related?) outside the two I listed, as I am not able to find much on this topic.

Comment: Having the same issue 9 months later. Seems like CDM will really benefit with a data modelling tool that allows you to build new custom entities and shows what the relations and dependencies between entities are. @Superman.Lopez any updates on since the last time you posted?

Comment: @mussi89 Unfortunately not.  I ended up writing my own classes similar to CDM, but not implementing the provided interfaces.  My thinking is that if needed in future I could easily refactor the classes to implement the interfaces, for now I don't see how CDM can benefit me.  As I mentioned, I moved on, but maybe you can ask the same question on the Github project to get a better idea how their project can benefit you; https://github.com/microsoft/CDM/issues